# Powershell issues with Start-Transcript

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to log my simple script for windows updates. When I to the Start-Transcript command it starts but it ends right after it starts. Currently running powershell 5.1 below is the code I am trying to log.

```
#Start Log
Start-Transcript -Path $logFolder\windowsupdate.$logDate.log

#Get and install Windows Updates
Get-WUInstall -MicrosoftUpdate -AcceptAll -IgnoreReboot
Get-WUInstall -MicrosoftUpdate -AcceptAll -Install -IgnoreReboot

#Set install from MS
#Add-WUServiceManager -ServiceID 7971f918-a847-4430-9279-4a52d1efe18d

#stop Logging
Stop-Transcript
```

The output is below. I started out some information. Also as you can see the start time and end time are the same but the script was still running when it ended the Transcript.

```
**********************
Windows PowerShell transcript start
Start time: 20190918224703
Username: ********
RunAs User: ********
Machine: ******** (Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.14393.0)
Host Application: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
Process ID: 9368
PSVersion: 5.1.14393.3053
PSEdition: Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.1.14393.3053
BuildVersion: 10.0.14393.3053
CLRVersion: 4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion: 3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion: 2.3
SerializationVersion: 1.1.0.1
**********************
Transcript started, output file is C:\********\WU-Logs\windowsupdate.2019-09-18-22-47.log
**********************
Windows PowerShell transcript end
End time: 20190918224703
**********************
```

Comment: i don't have those cmdlets ... but i suspect that they are starting a different process. have you checked `task manager` to see what is running?

Comment: I have not checked task manager but on my computer, it does log it the output from the cmdlets. Should have added this is on server 2012 R2. Also `Stop-Transcript` at the end is throwing an error saying Transcript is not running.

Comment: i am lost on this ... other than "the main script is really running to completion that quickly", i have no other ideas. [*sigh ...*]

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a solution for this, but experienced the same issue last week. It's definitely something in the `PSWindowsUpdate` module that breaks/stops transcription. The transcription log file immediately stops logging as soon as module is installed. I tried troubleshooting for a couple days before eventually removing the transcription altogether as a last resort. Sadly no option to Create issue on creator's Github either.